# Using layouts for different sdks

Tags: android, sdk, backwards-compatibility

So here is my declaration for my sdk settings:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

As you can see, my min is lower than my target. Now, when I design my layouts, I use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. Since `match_parent` wasn't added until API level 8, what will happen on a device that has an SDK version of level 7 and they go to load the layout with a View that uses `match_parent`? More importantly:

How can I make my app backwards compatible with API level 7, but still use features from higher APIs when they are available?

Comment: Just use `fill_parent`, if you want backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `fill_parent` and `match_parent` resolve to the value of -1, as per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html), so there is no compatibility issue with older versions of Android.

The Android SDK includes a tool, [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html), which can check for features that are only available in higher versions than your minimum API level. More details on how to run Lint can be found [in the tool's guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html).